act_connmark kernel module in RHEL
act_connmark kernel module is used by tc ... action connmark.
For some reason, I cannot find this module in RHEL, but it's available in Centos and Ubuntu.
yum -y install kernel-modules-extra installs many additional modules, but not this one.
Could it be installed from some other package? Or might be they removed it completely?
